# Django importing Models from template

Tags: django, django-models, extends, django-templates, django-database

In my django project, I have a base.html from which all my templates {% extends 'base.html' %}. In that base template I want to do this to a list of all my algorithms.

```
{% for algorithm in algorithms %}
   # list them out as links in nav bar
{% endfor %}
```

But I'm not passing algorithms to the base since it's just extending other templates.

I don't know how to solve this. My thought was to use {% load %} in the base template which would basically.

```
from algorithms.models import Algorithm
from django import template


register = template.Library()

def GetAlgorithmObjects():

  a = Algorithm.objects.all()

  return {'algorithms': a}
```

I'm not sure of how load works which would explain this failure.  How would you actually implement this or should I go a different path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with inclusion tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

In your app `algorithms` create directory `templatetags` and put a file in it named `algorithms_tags.py` (of course in this directory there must be a file named `__init__.py`)

Then the content of the file is similar to what you wrote:

```
from algorithms.models import Algorithm
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('algorithms/show_algorithms.html')
def show_algorithms():
    a = Algorithm.objects.all()
    return {'algorithms': a}
```

Then you need a template located at `algorithms/templates/algorithms/show_algorithms.html` with the following content:

```
{% for algorithm in algorithms %}
   # list them out as links in nav bar
{% endfor %}
```

You can use it in your `base.html` as follows:

```
{% load algorithms_tags %}

{% show_algorithms %}
```

Some explanations:

- In `{% load algorithms_tags %}` "algorithms_tags" is the name of the `.py` file created in the `templatetags` directory (without the extension)
- In `{% show_algorithms %}` "show_algorithms" is the name of the function decorated with `register.inclusion_tag` in `inclusion_tag.py`

Comment: How would I make it so that show_algorithm takes a string as an argument?  Something like {% show_algorithms("statistics") %}

Comment: It's simple. just add the argument to the function `def show_algorithms(some_name):` and in your template you use `{% show_algorithms "statistics" %}` or `{% show_algorithms some_name="statistics" %}` where `some_name` is the name of function argument.

Answer (score 2):

You would actually want to make a context processor to supply the algorithm objects to all templates.  context_processors are just functions that return objects to be used as context within any view.  So here is the code you need:

For this example, my app is called `core`. I have a python file in the app called `context_processors` and the function is `myuser`.  Here is my function code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import MyUser

def myuser(request):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = None

    if user:
        myuser = MyUser.objects.get(user=user)
        return {'myuser': myuser}
    else:
        # load a default user for testing
        myuser = MyUser.objects.all()[0]
        return {'myuser': myuser}
```

The `myuser()` function just returns my extended User model.  I created this so I could have the `MyUser` object available in all templates.

Then add this `context_processor` to you `settings.py`:

#### settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other default context processors
    'core.context_processors.myuser',
    )
```